# Update many records in a laravel relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-key-relationship

I have 4 tables that I'm trying to work with in Laravel and I can't figure out how to use eloquent to execute a particular query. I want to update all orders that belong to a user (through product_id) and that have null payout_id.

This raw sql statement works but I'm not sure how to use eloquent for this..perhaps [sync](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserting-related-models)?

```
UPDATE order_items i JOIN products p on (i.product_id = p.id)  SET i.payout_id = null where p.user_id = 3
```

**User Model**

**Product Model**
FK: user_id

**Order Model**
FK: product_id
FK: payout_id

**Payout Model**

I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a model for your tables `i` and `p`, see http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent for full information on model creation.

In the model for `i` you would then create a relationship to `p`:

```
 public function p()
 {
     return $this->('p','id','product_id');
 }
```

You can then run your query as follows:

```
$results = i::with('p')
->where('user_id', '=', 3)
->update(array('payout_id' => null));
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! This unfortunately gave me Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: update `order_items` set `payout_id` = 8, `updated_at` = 2014-05-02 15:52:21 where `user_id` = 3 and `payout_id` is null)

Comment: Sorry for the mix up there, bit of a typo, hows that.

Answer (score 0):

```
First define a function orders in User Model
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Orders', 'Product','user_id','product_id');
    }     



    User::where('id','=',$userid)->with(array('orders'=>function($query){
        $query->where('payout_id','=',0)->update(array('payout_id'=>$updatevalue));
    }))->first();
```

Comment: Thank you!

This seems like it should work but I may be missing something. 

`$payout_id = $payout->id;

User::where('id','=',$user_id)->with(array('orderItems'=>function($query){
 $query->where('payout_id',NULL)->update(array('payout_id'=>$payout_id));
}))->first();`

Gives me undefined variable $payout_id? Scope issue? If i replace the variable with a static value (11) i get `Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'updated_at' in field list is ambiguous